unable to access google account
when opening "Files" > Other Locations > my gmail address says invalid credentials for my gmail account
on the list on the left, just abobe "+Other Locations" is my gm ail address but it also says "unable to access" because of invalid credentials

Which version of Linux are you using?

thank you, online account is re-connected. All ok now

@Stephen Accept the answer below as correct by clicking on the gray check mark next to the answer and turn it green. This will mark your question as correctly answered and help others.

If you are using Gnome, it means you must re-connect your Google account in Settings -> Online Accounts
Step 1: Open your Settings

Step 2: Select Online Accounts

Step 3: Disconnect and reconnect your Google account.

You must know your Google password for this step.

